# Read a list of strings from text file and remove the extra quotes

Tags: python, list, parsing, text

In my text file, I have a list of strings as follows :

```
['', '"0=SYSEV,1=APPEV,2:3=VECEV"', '"ASEN"+$y', '"FALSE"', '"G"+$x+"ARBCFG"', '"G"+$x+"ARBPR"', '"HUGO:SECURE"', '"Internal"', '"SERIAL0:TRANSMIT"', '$fpi_mem_range', '$fpi_to_sri_base', '$fpi_to_sri_range', '$sx_fpi_base', '$sx_fpi_range', '$sx_sri_dest', '$trignum_g-1', '$x!=0', '$x!=1', '$x==1', '0', '0x0', '0x00', '0x0000', '0x00000000', '0x00000FFFF', '0x0000FFFF', '0x0D', '0x10', '0x1000', '0x10000000', '0x11001111', '0x11111100', '0xffc', '0xffffffff', '1', '1 clock cycle for generating the MSB', '10', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '115', '1156', '116', '117', '118', '1188', '119', '1192', '1196', '12', '120']
```

This list is written in text file using this code :

```
thefile = open('test.txt', 'w')
for item in thelist:
    thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

I want to read the list again. So I am using this code :

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

The list that I am obtaining is correct but the extracted strings contain extra quotes that I want to remove. This is the list that I obtained :

```
['','"0=SYSEV,1=APPEV,2:3=VECEV"','"ASEN"+$y','"FALSE"',....,'0x0000FFFF']
```

To remove the extra quotes, I used ast.literaleval() but I got this error :

```
 File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
 return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)

 File "<unknown>", line 1
 "ASEN"+$y

  ^
 SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

It seems that it removes the single quotes for all elements of the list even the one that we don't need to remove their quotes.
Any better ideas ?

Comment: Let your list be called `text`, does this achieve what you want? `for item in text:
 item=re.sub('["]',' ',item)
 print(item)`

Comment: that one will remove all the double quotes. For example this item  '"ASEN"+$y' will be 'ASEN+$y' which is not correct.

Comment: What should `"ASEN"+$y` become?

Comment: I aplogize. It worked as intended ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use re.sub to remove all double quote characters. Effectively this is done by matching the double quotes characters using regular expressions, and substituting an empty character instead.

```
import re
thelist = ['','"0=SYSEV,1=APPEV,2:3=VECEV"','"ASEN"+$y','"FALSE"','0x0000FFFF']

newlist = [];

for item in thelist:
    newlist.append(re.sub('["]','',item))
```

`newlist` will contain the elements from `thelist` without double quotes.

*Edit.*

You may also use `str.replace` method for improved performance as pointed out by **zwer** below.

```
for item in thelist:
  newlist.append(item.replace('"',''))
```